# SELECT COUNT(*) and SELECT COUNT(Primary Key) for PDO SELECT

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I have a login script which takes the user's email/password combination, runs a select query on it and logs the user in if the number of results returned is more than 1.

Script Example:

```
require("dbconnection.inc");
$email=$_POST['email'];
$pw=$_POST['pw'];
$login=$connection->prepare("SELECT `Password` FROM `Users` WHERE `Email`=:email");
$login->bindValue(":emailuser",$loginemail);
$login->execute();
$verifyemail=$loginuser->rowCount();
if($verifyemail > 0)
{
    //Login user
}
```

However, i saw in the PHP manual that rowCount() should not be used with PDO as not all databases support it, and that

```
$count = $pdo->query('select count(*) FROM blah WHERE blah')->fetchColumn(); 
echo $count;
```

should be used instead.

However, it got me wondering if i can simply use `count(PrimaryKey)` instead of `count(*)`.Is it possible to use `count(PrimaryKey)` instead of `count(*)` and if there are any drawbacks?

P.S I'm currently using MYSQL, and rowCount is working fine, and i'm not sure if i should even change my current code to a `COUNT(*)` instead.

Comment: Yes, you can use `COUNT(id)` if you want to. Personally I always count only the id's ( or other fields ) instead of using the `*` option.

Comment: Generally it's considered more efficient to use `count(PrimaryKey)` or even `count(1)`... though I believe some databases have optimised `count(*)` these days to match the efficiency of the other two variants

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [sql_func_count](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_func_count.asp)

SQL COUNT(column_name) Syntax

The COUNT(column_name) function returns the number of values (NULL values will not be counted) of the specified column:

```
SELECT COUNT(column_name) FROM table_name;
```

SQL COUNT(*) Syntax

The COUNT(*) function returns the number of records in a table:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM table_name;
```

SQL COUNT(DISTINCT column_name) Syntax

The COUNT(DISTINCT column_name) function returns the number of distinct values of the specified column:

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT column_name) FROM table_name;
```

Note: COUNT(DISTINCT) works with ORACLE and Microsoft SQL Server, but not with Microsoft Access.

**MySQL:**

In case of mysql read the following article from **MySQL Performance Blog** 
[COUNT(*) vs COUNT(col)](http://www.mysqlperformanceblog.com/2007/04/10/count-vs-countcol/)